# Make identical node in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Suppose there are two nodes:

1. user data    (inside "user data" we have:)

   unique id
   name: "abc"
   latitude: "123"
   longitude: "456"
2. user key     (inside "user key" we have:)

   unique id
   g: "awe46q"
   l
   0:123
   1:456

Here I want to save both "user data" & "user key" with the same unique id. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the push() method but it generates different unique ids. Will I have to use FirebaseAuth to make the unique id similar for "user data" & "user key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the push() method but it generates different unique ids.

That's expected behavior since calling `push()` multiple times, will always generate each time a new random id.

> Will I have to use FirebaseAuth to make the unique id similar for "user data" & "user key".

When it comes to users IDs, yes, the most appropriate solution is to implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and use the `UID` that is generated in this process. In the end, you can simply use the same `UID`, in every reference that you need, for example:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference userDataRef = rootRef.child("userData").child(uid); //One reference
userDataRef.setvalue(yourObject);
DatabaseReference otherUserDataRef = rootRef.child("otherUserData").child(uid); //Second reference
otherUserDataRef.setvalue(otherObject);
```

Comment: I tired out this and it was successfully saving "user data" & "user key" with same unique id(`uid`). But I want the same user to add multiple products and with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();` I can have only one unique id which gets overwrite when trying to new product. **So is there any other way that a single user can save multiple product with unique id for both "user data" & "user key".**

Comment: Good to hear that :) The `uid` should be used to identify the users in the different nodes in your database. However, to identify products, you should definitely use the `push()` method, so you can create a different id for each and every product.

Comment: Thanks it is retrieving all data from **currentUser**. But I want it to retrieve data from all the user, even if a user (_who is using the app to find products_) is not logged in, can we do that

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this community, please post another fresh question, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: For sure Alex Mamo :)

Comment: Your answers were good but it does not solve my problem. I want to retrieve all the users data or else **set both "user data" & "user key" with the same unique id.**

Comment: It's up to you to accept or not an answer but we usually stick to one question at a time. If you have another problem after the initial one is solved, you should post a new question for that problem with its own MCVE.

Comment: The last question is totally different than the initial one.

Comment: Yeah i will accept it at least I got some knowledge. Btw i have posted another question i hope you will check that. Thanks.

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.